# Linux Mint 18.2 (Sonya) Laptop Crashes (But Stays On) When the Power Goes Out

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint

I have a laptop running Linux Mint 18.2, and it works great ... until something interrupts the power.  When that happens the entire system hard crashes and kicks me out to a console-like screen with some error messages and such.

However, the laptop stays on and displays this screen, which means my battery *is* working ... there's just something going wrong in Linux when my laptop switches from AC to battery power.

I saw something about Windows users being able to disable a certain setting to fix this, but I didn't see any equivalent setting my power options.  Is there any way to solve this on Linux?

Comment: do you have TLP (Advanced Power Management) installed?

Comment: Yes, I have version 0.8-1

Comment: There have been quite a few issues with TLP (similar to yours), I would suggest to try and uninstall it to check if the issue has been caused by TLP.

Comment: Can you boot correctly on battery ?

Comment: I will try it and find out the next time I reboot (I have a lot of apps up ATM so I can't do it right now).  Thanks.

Comment: Yes I can boot just fine on battery.

Comment: What are the error messages when you are "kicked out"? Have you tried another battery?

Comment: It's a wall of text that there's no way I'm going to remember (and I can't take a screenshot or copy/paste it or anything).I really don't think it's a hardware issue though, since this doesn't happen in my Windows partition: it appears to be a Linux configuration problem of some sort.

Comment: Without some lead it will be extremely hard to diagnose. A low-tech idea: Take a video with your phone of the boot process.